# Permutation of composition factors?

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Suppose $G$ is a finite length (or finite) group, with composition series $1 = G_0 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq G_k = G$. Denote the composition factors of this series (up to isomorphism) by the ordered list $(A_1, A_2, \ldots A_k)$. Suppose that $1 = G'_0 \subseteq \ldots \subseteq G'_k = G$ is a different composition series, which composition factors $(A'_1, \ldots A'_k)$.

The Jordan-Holder theorem tells us that these factors are unique up to reordering. So, I can think of $(A'_1, A'_2, \ldots A'_k)$ as a permutation of $(A_1, \ldots, A_k)$. In particular, this is some element in $\sigma \in S_k$. I will write $(A'_1, A'_2, \ldots A'_k) = \sigma (A_1, \ldots, A_k)$ The jist of my question is this: is $\sigma^n (A_1, \ldots, A_k)$ also the composition factors of some series for $G$. More generally, if we let $N$ be the subgroup of $S_k$ generated by all the $\tau \in S_k$ so that $\tau (A_1, \ldots, A_k)$ corresponds to the composition factors of some composition series, is it again the case that, for any $\nu \in N$, $\nu (A_1, \ldots, A_k)$ corresponds to some composition series?

This holds trivially in uninteresting cases:

1. I can permute the composition factors of a finite abelian group in any way that I like. Likewise for any finite direct sum of simple groups. In this case, $S_k$ acts naturally and transitively on the possible orders of the composition factors of the group, although there may be some kernel due to repeated factors.
2. Other times, I am totally limited in the extent to which I can permute the composition factors - $S_n$ comes to mind ($n \geq 5$) comes to mind, as does $S_3$. (And also $S_4$, since the composition series is $1 \subset Z_2 \subset Z_2 \times Z_2 \subset A_4 \subset S_4$, which has composition factors $\{Z_2, Z_2, Z_3, Z_2\}$.) So in this case, I would say that the trivial group ($S_1$) acts naturally.
3. The dihedral groups are also uninteresting in this regard: In $Z_n \rtimes Z_2$ we need to factor $Z_n$ out first, since all the proper normal subgroups are contained in this cyclic subgroup, and we need the quotient to be of prime order. Thus we have the top term fixed and the rest can be permuted as in the finite abelian case.

Is there in general a (natural), transitive group action on the possible orders of the composition factors of a group?

Comment: @JackSchmidt  No, because there is only one possible order of composition factors, so $\{1\}$ acts transitively on the orders. Sorry if this wasn't clear from my question.

Comment: I cannot figure out exactly what you are asking. (I am not even sure which examples you are talking about when you say "In the first case" and "In the latter case".) Could you try and formulate your question more clearly?

Comment: @DerekHolt I updated my question. Hopefully it is more clear now.

Comment: Looks interesting now. I think the repeated factors make the question a little complicated, so if you can work on how to handle them, that will make your question easier to answer. For instance dihedral of order 12 has minor issues: the 2 on top cannot be moved, but the 2 in the middle/bottom can be moved. I'm fairly certain you can't just do it by "position" (so the permutation group cannot simply act on {1,2,...,k} in your notation).

Comment: Short version: No, if you mean the perm group acts on iso classes of simple groups. No, if you mean the perm group acts on positions. Maybe yes, if it acts in some blended way.

Comment: If those “no”s are enough, then I'll write them up, but most people want the answer to be “yes” when they ask a question like this. :-)

Comment: @JackSchmidt I'm very happy with a 'no' - I usually learn more that way. :-) If I can't find the counter examples you suggest are there then I'll ask for help, but otherwise it's a good excuse to get my hands dirty with some more examples of composition series. (Though if you could suggest a family of groups to look at, that would save me some time - there's a lot of other stuff I need to get through.)

Comment: @JackSchmidt (Usually when I ask questions like this it's so that I can stop playing with them and get back to doing exercises out my books, which I know are worth thinking about.)

Comment: @JackSchmidt In the $D_{12}$ case, isn't the action given by $<(12)>$?

Comment: In $D_{12}$ acting on positions, yes. Acting on isomorphism classes of simple groups, the group isn't transitive (or defined or something) since it can't move $A_3$ but it can move the isomorphic $A_1$ or $A_2$.

Comment: @JackSchmidt Okay. I was more interested in a transitive action on positions (my original motivation for this question was a much more easily answered question about  p-solvable groups, where my first thought was to try permuting the composition factors). Do you have in mind a counter example for the case of permutations on positions?

Comment: Yes, $C_5 \times S_3$ should be bad. Just using the position, you cannot tell if the factor is "top/middle" (C2), "middle/bottom" (C3), or "top/middle/bottom" (C5).

Comment: The name of the combinatorial structure is probably "graded posets whose automorphism group is transitive on maximal flags".